# Bootstrap3: Collapse/Accordion Validation error

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm getting a validation error of ' Duplicate ID accordion' when I'm using two bootstrap3 accordions on a single page.

In the first line there is 'id="accordion"', this is kind default bootstrap3 id, if I change it the accordion loses it's properties.

Default Accordion HTML Code:

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
      <div class="panel-body">
       Some Text in Acoordion
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
      <div class="panel-body">
       Some Text in Accordion
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
      <div class="panel-body">
      Some text in Accordion
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you change the id of the second accordion AND the data-parent attribute of its 'a' elements?

Comment: I tried changing the accordion id, but that disabled the collapse function.

Comment: Your accordion is generated by AJAX or something like that ?

Comment: @chandan Right, but did you also change the data-parent attribute of each 'a' element within the accordion to point to the new ID?

Comment: No I did not, I will try this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ID must be unique, you should replace the ID of the second accordion by another (different) and change the data-parant by the new ID

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
      <div class="panel-body">
       Some Text in Acoordion
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
[...]
</div>

<div class="panel-group" id="accordion2" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseFour" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseFour" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
      <div class="panel-body">
       Some Text in Acoordion
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseFive" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
  </div>
[...]
</div>
```

You can see an example here : http://jsfiddle.net/queval_j/1ae8goa6/